# Angular $http.post -> Express: stop numbers being turned into strings

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm trying to send data ($scope.resto is the model for all of the input fields in my form) from angular to express using

```
console.log($scope.resto);
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/new',
            contentType: 'application/json',
    params: $scope.resto....
```

$scope.resto is an object with various strings and number values.  And on the server side

```
app.post '/new', express.bodyParser(), (req, res) ->
    data = req.query
```

I tried using JSON.stringify($scope.resto) but resulted in a req.query (req.body is an empty object) is an object with integers as keys and each field being just one character from the json string. This is completely unusable but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Happy to add more code snippets but these are basics.

(When I send data to the client there is no problem preserving numeric values!)

Comment: Probably the data you are sending in your post is not initialised. Can you post a bit more of the controller code?

Comment: You can open the chrome developer tools to step through your code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending your form data as query parameters but using the POST method. Have you tried using **data** instead of **params**? **params** is something you'll typically use for "GET" requests.

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/new',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: $scope.resto //Assuming $scope.resto contains an object with simple key:value pairs
});
```

From what I've found, sending params with POST should cause the parameters to be added in the body of the request, but seeing you're probably sending a {...}, it might react strange.

My best shot at it, you'll have to provide more context if this doesn't resolve it.